# Simulate "Tabs" with Wirecloud

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I am working with wirecloud platform and I would like to know the following:

1.- Is is possible to resize the widget's width and height dinamically?

2.- Is it possible to fill a dashboard with widgets and ops dinamically?

Both questions aims to have a menu(widget) where users can click and change between different tabs.

Any help or idea would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT 06/08/15**

I am able to answer the second question: NO. As I can see in this [request](https://jira.fiware.org/browse/HELP-922), the ability to add/remove widgets dinamically is not available, although is thought to be in future releases of the platform. Next question: when is it going to be available?

**EDIT 13/08/15**

I expected using:

```
MashupPlatform.widget.drawAttention();
```

could trigger a tab change, but no luck.

**EDIT 27/08/15**

Finally, we found a workaround. We take advantage of the iFrame property by which you can access to parent's document. From there, we are able to read the elements representing the tabs and generate their clicks at will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for adding widgets and operators dynamically will be added on version 0.8.0, you can experiment with this feature if you install WireCloud from the develop branch on [github](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud). We are working on improving the [documentation](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/blob/develop/docs/slides/3.3.1_Javascript%20API.md#addwidget-method-example-usage) and polishing it for a new release at the end of September.

Although is great you find a work around using the iframe property for moving between tabs :), I recommend you to request the addition of such a feature using the [WireCloud's issue tracker](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues) ;-).

P.D. `MashupPlatform.widget.drawAttention();` need some fixes, but the idea is to provide some visual highlighting of widgets so user know there are updates in the widget. Something similar to the way google hangouts uses a green color for indicating the chat has new messages.